# Rudin W. Principles of Mathematical Analysis page 256

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms

https://notendur.hi.is/vae11/%C3%9Eekking/principles_of_mathematical_analysis_walter_rudin.pdf

(37) $\ \int_{\phi} cw =c\int_{\phi} w$

He says by (37),

(39)$\ \int_{\phi} (-w) =-\int_{\phi} dw$

How does property (39) Come about in page 256? I don't think he even defined the differential of a differential form.

Comment: Looks to me like a typo; should be $\int_\phi(-w)=-\int_\phi w$.

Comment: It's a typo: the differential of an $n$-form is an $n+1$-form, which is not defined on an $n$-dimensional surface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this off the unanswered queue,

> Looks to me like a typo; should be $\int_{\phi}(-w)=-\int_{\phi}w$.

*Answer by kimchi lover*